# Losing THIS inside class when using dot notation

Tags: javascript

Let's have 2 example classes:

```
class Lvl1 {

   constructor(rootContext) {
     this.rootContext = rootContext;
   }

   foo() {
     console.log(this.rootContext.data);
   }

}
```

And

```
class Lvl0 {

   constructor() {
     this.data = "Hello worlds!";
     this.callLv1 = new Lvl1(this);
   }


}
```

The *Lvl0* class stores in *this* a method from *Lvl1* class and passes *this* so the same method in *Lvl1* can access the context of *Lvl0*.

If you then do:

```
const el = new Lvl0();
el.callLv1.foo();
```

You get "Hello worlds!" as expected.

In my practical application tho, I have the path to the **foo** function in a String, as "callLv1.foo". So I wrote a simple function that accesses the object by dot notation:

```
const accessByDotNotation = (query, object) => {

    let el = object;
    query.split(".").forEach(fragment => el = el[fragment]);
    return el;


};
```

If I then do:

```
const el = new Lvl0();
accessByDotNotation('callLv1.foo', f)();
```

And that does not work, it gives a

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rootContext' of undefined

So the content of this in the second class got lost somehow. I tried a more robust way to access the object using the [dot-object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-object) library but I got the same error.

Here's everything put together:

```js
class Lvl1 {

   constructor(rootContext) {
     this.rootContext = rootContext;
   }

   foo() {
     console.log(this.rootContext.data);
   }

}

class Lvl0 {

   constructor() {
     this.data = "Hello worlds!";
     this.callLv1 = new Lvl1(this);
   }

}

const accessByDotNotation = (query, object) => {

    let el = object;
    query.split(".").forEach(fragment => el = el[fragment]);
    return el;


};

const f = new Lvl0();


//This works:
f.callLv1.foo();

//This does not work:
accessByDotNotation('callLv1.foo', f)();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's the same reason why `const fn = f.callLv1.foo; fn();` fails too: you lost your context.

Comment: there is a binding issue (it looks like) other's have pointed out arrow functions... my preff when working with classes is to bind the methods in the constructor (early react style) so this.function=this.funciton.bind(this)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably messed up the function binding in `accessByDotNotation`

This might not necessarily be completely advisable, but you can force binding like this:

```js
const accessByDotNotation = (query, object) => {

    let el = object;
    query.split(".").forEach(fragment => {
      const originalEl = el;
      el = el[fragment];
      if (typeof el === 'function') {
        el = el.bind(originalEl);
      }
    });
    return el;


};
```

You're binding the function the the object it's connected off of at each iteration, if `el[fragment]` is a function

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions retain the `this` context. Converting `foo` to an arrow function gives the desired result

```js
class Lvl1 {
  constructor(rootContext) {
    this.rootContext = rootContext;
  }

  foo = () => {
    console.log(this.rootContext.data);
  }
}

class Lvl0 {
  constructor() {
    this.data = "Hello worlds!";
    this.callLv1 = new Lvl1(this);
  }
}

const accessByDotNotation = (query, object) => {
  let el = object;
  query.split(".").forEach(fragment => el = el[fragment]);
  return el;
};

const f = new Lvl0();

//This works:
f.callLv1.foo();

//This now works too:
accessByDotNotation('callLv1.foo', f)();
```